# Change name tabs foundation for apps

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm new in foundation for apps. I have to use tabs but i have a problem with titles. I wanna use a two line name. e.g. "Tab < br > 1". How can i do it? Thanks

```
<div zf-tabs="">
   <div zf-tab="" title="Tab 1">
      Tab content 1
   </div>
   <div zf-tab="" title="Tab 2">
      Tab content 2
   </div>
   <div zf-tab="" title="Tab 3">
      Tab content 3
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the core file "foundation-apps-templates.js" (or the min version). There you can find the template for the zfTabs directive.

I've changed this line:

```
ng-click="makeActive()">{{ title }}</div>
```

For this:

```
ng-click="makeActive()" ng-bind-html="title" ></div>
```

This worked for me.
Good luck.